# How to run maven project on jetty in Intellij as in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

Maven project (project name: english) [vaadin, jetty] runs in Eclipse without any problem. How to run/configure exactly the same project in Intellij? Run/Apply options are not available after below configuration. In Eclipse I set, Base directory `[${workspace_loc:/english}]`, Goals [jetty:run], JRE, Source (english project). How to set it in Intellij?

[eclipse1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK2H2.png)

[eclipse2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtHnU.png)

[eclipse3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ipiF.png)

[intellij1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz8EW.png)

[intellij2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PytVb.png)

Comment: You need to create new Run configuration, then choose Maven and then fill all the same stuff like goals, project root folder. The only way is that JDK for the project might be configured separately

Comment: You are trying to edit the default configuration in IntelliJ IDEA instead of creating a new one using the + button, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html.

Comment: Ok. Run : java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo not present

Comment: Try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you need to add **jetty plugin for maven** as a dependency, if you don't have it already in your pom.xml. More about jetty maven plugin can be found [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html)
If you were running the project via embedded jetty plugin in eclipse, same pom.xml configuration should run successfully run when you issue same command in intellij IDE.

If there are any issues on your build, try with a "clean rebuild" before you start doing anything else. You can do that via the following command in your terminal:

```
mvn clean install jetty:run
```

You will need access your console (terminal), i.e. via **Alt + F12** keys. You also need to be in the same directory that you have the **pom.xml** in your project.

The command will basically clean up (i.e. delete) previously build project and do a fresh rebuild of your project, then run it via embedded jetty plugin.
Be sure to read a brief introduction to maven commands: [Maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) if needed.

After you successfully issued this command for the first time, I think you can can also issue **jetty:run** via **View -> Tool windows -> maven project**.

You can usually access it also on your right side of intellij IDE (the "m" icon, maven projects).